# VBA Runtime 424 Object Required

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy multiple sheets to new workbook. I need copy 3 sheets from different workbooks to new create workbook in one sheet.

this is my code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Path = "C:\Users\vnohavcova\Desktop\New folder\DB earnie report\"
fileName = Dir(Path & "*.xls")

Do While fileName <> ""
    Workbooks.Open fileName:=Path & fileName, ReadOnly:=True
    For Each sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        sheet.Copy After:=DestWkb.Sheets(1)
    Next sheet
    Workbooks(fileName).Close
    fileName = Dir()
Loop
```

Comment: either you are missing a crucial part of your code, or where are you setting `DestWkb` ? maybe you meant `Set DestWkb = Workbooks.Open fileName:=Path & fileName, ReadOnly:=True` , or is it `ThisWorkbook` ?

Comment: Do you not need to define Path and fileName?

Comment: Oh sorry yeah I set up 
Dim DestWbk As Workbook
Set DestWkb = Workbooks.Add